# Could not calculate the upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, do-release-upgrade

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug update-manager' in a terminal.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. More information is needed before the community be able to help you. First and foremost, any of those possible causes applies to your case?

Comment: The changes between 10.04 and 12.04 are big enough that I would personally recommend a clean install of 12.04 and then copy your data over having backed up first.  I would not consider an upgrade.

Comment: You probably did all this, but did you do an sudo apt-get update, upgrade, and then install -f to ensure that all possible 10.04 updates have been applied and the dependencies are all fixed?

Comment: Usually this is due to one or more PPAs - you should consider `purge`ing your PPA packages first before upgrading.  Then you can reinstall your PPAs (if they exist for 12.04).  Let us know what happens if you do this.